# LibGDX Actor in stage not receiving click events

Tags: java, android, input, libgdx

Edit:

I think it's something to do with the way I setBounds()...
A similar project I have (that actually works), involves a moving box that changes color when clicked... A box - not a circle. I think this is a clue.

OG Post:

1. Subclassed Actor.
2. Put Actor in a Stage.
3. Added a ClickListener inside Actor.constructor.
4. Set Stage as inputProcessor.
5. But when I click on the Actor, nothing seems to happen.

There is no response - when I try to click the actor.
It's suppose to change color, increase speed and track input x/ys.

It's weird 'cause I built a very similar program that works. So why doesn't this?

The actor is represented by a circle drawn by the ShapeRenderer. I assume it's "click" boundary must be just a rectangle?

HelloGDXGame.java

```
@Override
   public void create() {
      SCREEN_WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2;
      SCREEN_HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2;
      rowHeight = 80;
      touchPos = new Vector3();

      batch = new SpriteBatch();

      font = new BitmapFont();
      font.setColor(Color.PINK);
      font.setScale(4.0f);

    ball = new Ball(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, 180, 90, this);

      stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));

      stage.addActor(ball);

      Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
   }

   @Override
   public void render()
   {        
      Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      // Translate inputs x/y
      touchPos.x = Gdx.input.getX();
      touchPos.y = (Gdx.input.getY() - Gdx.graphics.getHeight()) * -1;

      stage.act();
      stage.draw();

      // UI, to check it all works (it doesn't)
      batch.begin();
      font.draw(batch, "Ball Class: Taps: " + ball.getTaps(), 64, SCREEN_HEIGHT - (rowHeight * 8));
      font.draw(batch, "Main Class: Touch X: " + touchPos.x, 64, SCREEN_HEIGHT - (rowHeight * 7));
      font.draw(batch, "Main Class: Touch Y: " + touchPos.y, 64, SCREEN_HEIGHT - (rowHeight * 6));
      font.draw(batch, "Ball Class: Touch X: " + ball.getScreenX(), 64, SCREEN_HEIGHT - (rowHeight * 5));
      font.draw(batch, "Ball Class: Touch Y: " + ball.getScreenY(), 64, SCREEN_HEIGHT - (rowHeight * 4));
      batch.end();
   }
```

Ball.java

```
public Ball(float xPos, float yPos, float xSpeed, float ySpeed, HelloGdxGame game) {
      super();
      this.game = game;
      renderer = new ShapeRenderer();

      taps = 0;
      radius = 196;

      super.setBounds(xPos - radius, yPos - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);

// just to check it's working
screenXY = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

      this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
      this.ySpeed = ySpeed;

    this.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);

      this.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                doStuff(x, y);
                return false;
            }
         });

      changeColour();  // sets random color
   }

   private void doStuff(float screenX, float screenY) {
      screenXY.x = screenX;
      screenXY.y = screenY;
      changeColour();
      taps++;

      // Increase speed
      if (xSpeed > 0) xSpeed++;
      else xSpeed--;
      if (ySpeed > 0) ySpeed++;
      else ySpeed--;
   }

   @Override
   public void act(float delta) {
      super.act(delta);

// move
      super.setX(super.getX() + (xSpeed * delta));
    super.setY(super.getY() + (ySpeed * delta));

// Bounce horizontally
      if (super.getX() < 0 || super.getX() + (radius / 2) > Gdx.graphics.getWidth()) {
         super.setX(super.getX() - (xSpeed * delta));
        xSpeed *= -1;
      }

// Bounce vertically
      if (super.getY() < 0 || super.getY() + (radius / 2) > Gdx.graphics.getHeight()) {
         super.setY(super.getY() - (ySpeed * delta));
         ySpeed *= -1;
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
      super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

    renderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
      renderer.setColor(r, g, b, 1);
      renderer.circle(super.getX(), super.getY(), radius);
      renderer.end();
   }
```

Comment: upload your code somewhere, or better tell me what you changed since our last working version. There is a good way to debug. You just return to that working version and carefully add new lines and check if it's still working

Comment: Hello, you. I've yet to learn how to use git properly (plus, working on phone anyway / no pc), so I'll just add the two files to my pastebin and hope you don't mind going through the process of making a new libgdx project...  x_x          That paste:  https://pastebin.com/u/StudioGilliam/1/0/1/?guest=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Take a changed Ball from [here](https://pastebin.com/y8ePzdtW)

2)
Change

```
SCREEN_WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2;
SCREEN_HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2;
```

To

```
SCREEN_WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
SCREEN_HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
```

This is illogical.

Comment: @StudioGilliam what exactly you don't understand. I could explain. You have to research for a problem and debug more carefully instead of posting every faced problem to StackOverflow

Comment: @StudioGilliam i can't do that for you every time